# relation does not exist in postgreSQL but already exist

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I've read a lot of articles about my problem but no one solve it. So u can see my code here

```
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('url_of_my_db')
con = None
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)
    cur = con.cursor()
    
    print('PostgreSQL database version:')
    #cur.execute('SELECT version()')
    #cur.execute('SELECT * FROM qwerty')
    
    #cur.execute(sql.SQL('SELECT * FROM {}').format(sql.Identifier('qwerty')))
    #cur.execute(sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} (chat_id, username, created_on) VALUES (8985972942, vovakirdan, 2022-01-05)").format(sql.Identifier('users')))
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO users (chat_id, username, created_on)
                    VALUES (3131,
                    vovakirdan,
                    2022-01-05)""")
    

    # display the PostgreSQL database server version
    db_version = cur.fetchone()
    print(db_version)
       
     # close the communication with the HerokuPostgres
    cur.close()
except Exception as error:
    print('Cause: {}'.format(error))

finally:
    # close the communication with the database server by calling the close()
    if con is not None:
        con.close()
        print('Database connection closed.')
```

and in my DB table named "users" (named without quotes) are exist, but I still have this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef64B.png)

...relation "users" does not exist

all the #commented code doesn't work and send the same error besides SELECT version(), it works perfectly that proves that connection works.

Comment: Do not argue with the compiler - it **wins every time**. If it says the table does not exist then the fact is that table *does not exist*. You need to figure out the issue. You may be in the wrong database, the schema the table exists in is not in your path, perhaps it actually is defined as "Users", etc.

Comment: BTW: even after correcting the non-existing table your insert will fail. Postgres (and any other RDBMS that I know of) will see `2022-01-05` not as a date but as an arithmetic expression; resulting in attempting to insert the integer 2016 into a date column and raising an exception. You should use a proper date literal: `DATE '2022-01-05'`.

Comment: And so how can I create a right DB that postgre loves? Can you advice me where can I notice that moment? Because I’ve tried a lot of different names and ways to create (console and postgre admin) database. I think I’m not doing it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that PostgreDB wants me to use `SELECT colum FROM schema.table` instead of `SELECT colum FROM table`. And that's all. Thanks everyone